# Django GenericRelation doesn't save related object's id - is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: django, generic-relationship

I have a model with a generic relation (call it A), when creating an instance of this object I pass an instance of another model (call it B) as the initializer of the content_object field (via kwargs of the constructor).

If I don't save B before creating A then when saving A the content_object_id is saved to the db as NULL. If I save B **before passing it to the constructor of A** then everything's allright.

It's not logical. I assumed that the ID of the related object (B) is fetched when doing A.save() and it should throw some kind of an exception if B isn't saved yet but it just fails silently. I don't like the current solution (saving B beforhand) because we don't know yet if I will be always willing to keep the object, not just scrap it, and there are performance considerations - what if I will add some another data and save it once more shortly after.

```
class BaseNodeData(models.Model):
    ...
    extnodedata_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True)
    extnodedata_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    extnodedata = generic.GenericForeignKey(ct_field='extnodedata_content_type', fk_field='extnodedata_object_id')

class MarkupNodeData(models.Model):
    raw_content = models.TextField()
```

Suppose we do:

```
markup = MarkupNodeData(raw_content='...')
base = BaseNodeData(..., extnodedata=markup)
markup.save()
base.save()
# both records are inserted to the DB but base is stored with extnodedata_object_id=NULL

markup = MarkupNodeData(raw_content='...')
base = BaseNodeData(..., extnodedata=markup)
base.save()
markup.save()
# no exception is thrown and everything is the same as above

markup = MarkupNodeData(raw_content='...')
markup.save()
base = BaseNodeData(..., extnodedata=markup)
base.save()
# this works as expected
```

Of course I can do it this way, but it doesn't change anything:

```
base = BaseNodeData(...)
base.extnodedata = markup
```

My question is - is this a bug in django which I should report or maybe I'm doing something wrong. Docs on GenericRelations aren't exactly verbose.

Comment: Can you show us some code? Model definitions and the related view code should do it

Comment: Views are irrelevant here and the actual code is too complicated for pasting it here so I will prepare a simplified demonstration here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I decided to take some more time to investigate the django sources and came up with a solution myself. I subclassed the GenericForeignKey. The code should be self-explanatory.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.db.models import signals

class ImprovedGenericForeignKey(generic.GenericForeignKey):
    """
    Corrects the behaviour of GenericForeignKey so even if you firstly
    assign an object to this field and save it after its PK gets saved.

    If you assign a not yet saved object to this field an exception is 
    thrown upon saving the model.
    """

    class IncompleteData(Exception):
        message = 'Object assigned to field "%s" doesn\'t have a PK (save it first)!'

        def __init__(self, field_name):
            self.field_name = field_name

        def __str__(self):
            return self.message % self.field_name

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        signals.pre_save.connect(self.instance_pre_save, sender=cls, weak=False)
        super(ImprovedGenericForeignKey, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)

    def instance_pre_save(self, sender, instance, **kwargs):
        """
        Ensures that if GenericForeignKey has an object assigned
        that the fk_field stores the object's PK.
        """

        """ If we already have pk set don't do anything... """
        if getattr(instance, self.fk_field) is not None: return

        value = getattr(instance, self.name)

        """
        If no objects is assigned then we leave it as it is. If null constraints
        are present they should take care of this, if not, well, it's not my fault;)
        """
        if value is not None:
            fk = value._get_pk_val()

            if fk is None:
                raise self.IncompleteData(self.name)

            setattr(instance, self.fk_field, fk)
```

I think that this should be considered a bug in django, so I will report it and see how it turns out.

Comment: Have you actually reported this behaviour? I'm currently experiencing a similar behaviour where if I'm linking an already saved model instance to a model with a generic FK. Since I'm doing it programatically I first run full_clean and if I then save the object, it actually gets saved as it should (linking works).
BUT if i wrap the save method in a transaction.atomic(), it throws an error "None Type has no Attribute pk" (or similar, haven't the exception at hand) and of course, nothing gets saved.

Comment: Yes, AFAIR I've even prepared a patch. Unfortunately the last time I had to do anything with django was 10 years ago. You should get a golden shovel 

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it is strange that you can save A without saving B beforehand.

But I can not think of a case where you will set a relation to an object that you don't want to keep. Makes no sense having a relation to an object that does not exist ;-)
Thus saving B beforehand is fine for me.

Not sure whether this helps, but the create method, as posted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569844/django-signals-implementing-on-save-listner/4570765#4570765), might give you an idea what you can also do with generic relations.

Comment: In my case it makes a lot of sense. I've got the BaseNodeData model and a few other models which contain additional data. I've also got a composite class Node (and its derivates) which wraps around this two models (BaseNodeData and the one of the other). So in my code, you don't create the model instances directly, instead you create the wrapper. It's counter-intuitive that the wrapper saves the data immediately upon instantiation (in terms of my code).

Comment: Oh and I'd like to emphasize that it's not only that you have to save B before saving A - you have to save B before even assigning it to a generic relation's object field!

Answer (score 0):

An instance of B has a pk of None prior to save, and your extnodedata_object_id field allows null values, so the save of the A instance is valid.

It sounds like what might work for you is to override A's save to properly handle new instances of B; e.g. (untested):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    b = self.extnodedata
    if b and b.pk is None:
        b.save()
        self.extnodedata = b
    return super(BaseNodeData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it should work but still it's still kind of a workaround. I'll test it and let you know. extnodedata_object_id allows null values because I don't always have a related object and GenericForeignKey can't have null=True. Still, its weird that the extnodedata_object_id is set on assigning object to the field and not on saving.

Comment: It works but I do not want to force saving. The crucial part is the assigning - that's when the pk field gets updated.